# Sqoop Import Java Client

Tags: java, oracle, hdfs, sqoop, sqoop2

I have done sqoop importer java class for importing oracle data to my HDFS. But Im getting error as `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal`. Any one knows why this happens and what should be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems that you are passing an Integer value in the method constructTextConditions of GenericJdbcPartitioner class when is waiting for a Big Decimal. You must be sure of the data that you are introducing there.

Comment: Yes. Im using sqoop 1.99.3. It happens only when number of splits 1. Means unique values partition field for all records .

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the very same problem using the [sqoop](/questions/tagged/sqoop) options

```
--hcatalog-database 
--hcatalog-table
```

With this parameters [hive](/questions/tagged/hive) gets in and is able to convert [avro](/questions/tagged/avro) types (or in my case `parquet type`, even `timestamp`)  into  ***oracle data types***